# Crafty.js looping after upgrade to 0.4.1

Tags: javascript, debugging, webos, craftyjs

I don't know if [Crafty.js](http://craftyjs.com/) is popular on Stack Overflow yet or not, but I've been using it, and I didn't get an answer from the mailing list, so I figured I'd try here.

I have some code that worked fine under release 0.3.x, but when I upgraded to 0.4.1, after fixing all of the API changes, I found that the Crafty.js code goes into an infinite loop that eventually uses all system resources and crashes my system.  In this case my system is a Palm Pixi Plus phone or the webOS emulator.

Anyone have any good ideas on what may have happened to cause this?  I can post code if you want, but I don't think it will be helpful.

As a side question, how can I get in to debug looping JavaScript like this?  I can't seem to successfully halt and enter the process mid loop:  the debugger won't let me in until *after* the system crashes.

Comment: I should add that no one else seems to be having this problem, just me, so I suspect it has something to do with webOS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, figured it out.  Seems to have something to do with the `Collision` component.  Will look into it further, but otherwise this question is done.